# C++ declaring an abstract class as friend class

Tags: c++

When and why would you declare an abstract class as a friend class?

I am trying to read the source code of [levelDb](https://github.com/google/leveldb)

It has an interface (abstract class) DB which does not have access to DB_Impl:

```
class DB {
 public:
  static Status Open(const Options& options,
                     const std::string& name,
                     DB** dbptr);
  DB() { }
  virtual ~DB();
  virtual Status Put(const WriteOptions& options,
                     const Slice& key,
                     const Slice& value) = 0;
  virtual Status Delete(const WriteOptions& options, const Slice& key) = 0;
  virtual Status Write(const WriteOptions& options, WriteBatch* updates) = 0;
  virtual Status Get(const ReadOptions& options,
                     const Slice& key, std::string* value) = 0;
  virtual Iterator* NewIterator(const ReadOptions& options) = 0;
  virtual const Snapshot* GetSnapshot() = 0;
  virtual void ReleaseSnapshot(const Snapshot* snapshot) = 0;
  virtual void GetApproximateSizes(const Range* range, int n,
                                   uint64_t* sizes) = 0;
  virtual void CompactRange(const Slice* begin, const Slice* end) = 0;
 private:
  // No copying allowed
  DB(const DB&);
  void operator=(const DB&);
};
```

and the implementation DB_Impl.

In db_impl.h:

```
class DBImpl : public DB {
  public:
    ... // implementation of the DB interface
  private:
    friend class DB;
    ... // internal methods and variables
}
```

Why is the abstract class DB declared as a friend class of DBImpl?

Comment: _"Why is the abstract class DB declared as a friend class of DBImpl?"_ We can't tell without seeing more context, but it's probably a serious design flaw. Unless `DB` doesn't know about `DBImpl` (which it shouldn't in a proper design) there's no advandage of `friend`.

Comment: Can you see the link to the source code now? I have also put the path to the corresponding file in the description.

Comment: I don't care about links and won't follow them, improve your question with providing the necessary context.

Comment: SO questions must be self-contained. References to external material are often fine, but the question itself must be understandable without following links.

Comment: Thanks. This is my first question on SO and I will definitely follow the rules on SO to make my question understandable. I have updated the question to show that DB does not have access to DBImpl. Please leave me a comment if the question is still confusing.

Comment: Perhaps it's indeed unneeded. There's a lot of less than perfect code out there.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class can have (and often has) non-abstract parts, for example normal member functions.

In your example, `DB` may have some normal member function `f() { /* ... */ }`. Furthermore, the class design may be such that `DB` is aware of certain derived classes. This is often, but not always, a sign of broken class design. So `f` may actually take a `DBImpl` argument and need to access some of its private members. In such a scenario, `friend` achieves the desired results.

Here is a complete example:

```
class DBImpl;

class DB {
public:
    virtual ~DB() {}

    void f(DBImpl& db_impl); // DB is aware of a derived class

private:
    virtual void virtual_function() = 0; // just to make the class abstract
};

class DBImpl : public DB {
private:
    void virtual_function() override {} // just to make the class concrete
    void g() {} // DBImpl wants only DB to be able to call this

    friend class DB;
};

void DB::f(DBImpl& db_impl) {
    db_impl.g(); // DB can call DBImpl's private member function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the static function DB::Open in DB class is using DBImpl  private/protected member variables/function.

Also if you havent shown the complete DB class declaration here and it has extra code please check if there is any non pure virtual function of DB class, it may have instance of DBImpl and access to its private member variables. This function can be inherited in derived classes and if called using derived class instance it will work fine.

Hope this helps.